# How can i verify if the installed oracle 11g is licensed or not

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am in the process of moving an old server to AWS and as part of the transition I need to move the oracle 11g db server installed on it.

I am not sure how can I verify if the installed version is licensed or not, and if it is licensed what is the CSI number?

```
SQL> select * from v$license


SESSIONS_MAX SESSIONS_WARNING SESSIONS_CURRENT SESSIONS_HIGHWATER  USERS_MA CPU_COUNT_CURRENT CPU_CORE_COUNT_CURRENT CPU_SOCKET_COUNT_CURRENT CPU_COUNT_HIGHWATER CPU_CORE_COUNT_HIGHWATER CPU_SOCKET_COUNT_HIGHWATER
------------ ---------------- ---------------- ------------------ --------- ----------------- ---------------------- ------------------------ ------------------- ------------------------ --------------------------
       0                0               24                 25         0                 8                       8                        1                  8                       8                       1
```

Comment: You can have an answer for your question here: [https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60054/how-to-verify-an-oracle-database-license]

Comment: There isn't anything in the actual database which can give you this information. Somebody in your organisation should be tracking the paperwork. If they haven't been then you will probably need to approach [Oracle Licensing Management Services](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/license-management-services/). I say "you" but this is a management task. It would be worth verifying which options you've been using. [Find out more](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/tracking-database-feature-usage)

Comment: @Abhinav I tried it but then I have to call Oracle and I am not sure what will happen if the DB we are using comes out to be unlicensed!!

Comment: @Chunky Don’t worry. Just make a call & get the details.